# npx create-react-app not showing latest bump to webpack-dev-server 3.11.0

Tags: npm, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, npx, yargs

This is my first SO question, so apologies for the lengthy amount of code. I'm trying to start a new project with `create-react-app`. I ran the following command:

```
npx create-react-app jam-box --use-npm
```

because I want to use npm instead of yarn, and everything works, the project boilerplate is created. But there's a security vulnerability with one of the dependencies of react-scripts:

```
[Angie @ ~/jam-box](master)
$ npm audit

                       === npm audit security report ===                        

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ yargs-parser                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=13.1.2 <14.0.0 || >=15.0.1 <16.0.0 || >=18.1.2             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-scripts                                                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > yargs > yargs-parser    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 1 low severity vulnerability in 922235 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
[Angie @ ~/jam-box](master)
$
```

I tried to run `npm audit fix`, but that didn't work. I went to both the webpack-dev-server github and the create-react-app github and it looked like they were already addressing this security issue, and as of two days ago, the issue was fixed and merged into the create-react-app master.

*When running `npm i react-scripts@latest` inside my project:*

```
[Angie @ ~/jam-box](master)
$ npm i react-scripts@latest
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of sass@^1.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-scripts@3.4.1
updated 1 package and audited 922235 packages in 46.013s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I was having this problem for days and was waiting to see if they would resolve it before trying to create a new `create-react-app` project. But today when I tried again to run `npx create-react-app jam-box --use-npm`, the security vulnerability was still there. I even tried running `npm install react-scripts@latest` and the vulnerability was still there. When I looked at my package-lock.json it says that react-scripts still was using the previous version of webpack-dev-server instead of the latest bump to 3.11.0. I don't know why when I run `npx create-react-app` that this isn't reflecting the latest master branch of create-react-app. I just want to run create-react-app to the latest version, any help would be appreciated.

```
npx create-react-app jam-box --use-npm
npx: installed 98 in 9.648s

Creating a new React app in /Users/Angie/jam-box.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/Angie/jam-box/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/Angie/jam-box/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/Angie/jam-box/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /Users/Angie/jam-box/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /Users/Angie/jam-box/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /Users/Angie/jam-box/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react@16.13.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1620 packages from 760 contributors and audited 922030 packages in 107.471s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4
+ @testing-library/react@9.5.0
+ @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1
added 36 packages from 56 contributors and audited 922236 packages in 19.35s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

removed 1 package and audited 922235 packages in 12.693s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Created git commit.

Success! Created jam-box at /Users/Angie/jam-box
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd jam-box
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been chasing down this vulnerability hoping to fix it, too!

My understanding is that react-scripts hasn't updated their dependencies to point to webpack-dev-server 3.11.0. Since webpack-dev-server is a dependency of react-scripts, react-scripts needs to update this in their codebase. It's not something we can change in our dependencies.

As you pointed out, webpack-dev-server updated their dependency on yargs to deal with the "security vulnerability in yargs-parser (#2566) (41d1d0c)" (webpack-dev-server release notes: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases).

But react-scripts (which is maintained and used by create-react-app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts) has not yet updated their dependency on webpack-dev-server to use the new 3.11.0 version.

I think this can be brought up to them as a concern asking them to update their dependency on weback-dev-server to point to the newest one which will resolve a security vulnerability, but I am not sure how this is done exactly, to be honest.